# Create table Error MySQL Varchar Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I'm trying to create 2 tables with one foreign key but mysql says:

> #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint. (users_gifts)

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `gifts`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gifts` (
  `gift_code` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `gift_redeemcredit` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `gift_redeemurl` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT '#',
  `gift_description` VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
  `gift_expirydate` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`gift_code`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `users_gifts`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_gifts` (
  `user_code` INT NOT NULL,
  `gift_code` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `usergift_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  INDEX `users_gifts_to_gifts_idx` (`gift_code` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `users_gifts_to_gifts`
    FOREIGN KEY (`gift_code`)
    REFERENCES `gifts` (`gift_code`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: There is no any problem with your query check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee3c9

Comment: Thank you, but i dont know why Phpmyadmin dont create this tables, if i try in my local server it works.

Answer (score 0):

you have no error in your code , but propably you have already created this foreign key .

try that before creating your tables.

```
    ALTER TABLE `users_gifts` DROP FOREIGN KEY `users_gifts_to_gifts` ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem set the DEFAULT CHARACTER SET to all the tables:

```
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```